# CreateProcess is able to execute batch files, but documentation says the opposite

Tags: windows, batch-file, winapi, createprocess

Consider the following files:

`a.bat`:

```
@echo Hello from bat %1
```

and `c.cpp`:

```c
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void check(TCHAR *cmd, TCHAR *args) {
  STARTUPINFO sinf;
  PROCESS_INFORMATION pinf;
  memset(&sinf, 0, sizeof sinf);
  sinf.cb = sizeof(sinf);

  CreateProcess(cmd, args, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &sinf, &pinf);
  WaitForSingleObject(pinf.hProcess, INFINITE);
}

int main() {
  TCHAR cmd1[] = L"a";
  TCHAR cmd2[] = L"a.bat";
  TCHAR cmdargs1[] = L"a argument";
  TCHAR cmdargs2[] = L"a.bat argument";
  TCHAR args[] = L"argument";

  #define run_check(a, b) printf(#a " + " #b "\n"); fflush(stdout); check(a, b)
  run_check(cmd1, cmdargs1);
  run_check(cmd1, cmdargs2);
  run_check(cmd1, args);

  run_check(cmd2, cmdargs1);
  run_check(cmd2, cmdargs2);
  run_check(cmd2, args);

  run_check(NULL, cmdargs1);
  run_check(NULL, cmdargs2);
  printf("Done\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Note that I haven't specified `cmd.exe` in any of calls to `CreateProcess`, while MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that I have to do it:

> To run a batch file, you must start the command interpreter; set lpApplicationName to cmd.exe and set lpCommandLine to the following arguments: /c plus the name of the batch file.

However, I get the following output:

```
cmd1 + cmdargs1
cmd1 + cmdargs2
cmd1 + args
cmd2 + cmdargs1
  Hello from bat argument
cmd2 + cmdargs2
  Hello from bat argument
cmd2 + args
"argument" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
NULL + cmdargs1
NULL + cmdargs2
  Hello from bat argument
Done
```

This means that whenever `.bat` extension is explicitly specified either in `lpApplicationName` or `lpCommandLine`, batch file is successfully started. This works wit `.cmd` too, but not with `.vbs`. Does anyone know reason behind such behavior and difference between practice and documentation? Is such behavior 'an accident' or it persists among different Windows versions? (I use Windows 7 HP) Is there any point in documentation from which one can infer such behavior?

Comment: Have you checked the file associations in the control panel?  Is .bat associated with any program?

Comment: Yes, it's associated with cmd.exe. But vbs is associated with wscript, for example, and it does not work. Looks like batch is a very specific file type.

Comment: Yes, thats quite strange. I noticed that JRE somewhat encourage this usage.BTW: I have asked on OpenJDK's core-lib-dev mailinglist, how they think this is valid.

Comment: @rri File associations are a feature of the Shell, not the core OS. `CreateProcessW` doesn't know about the Shell. File associations have no bearing here.

Answer (score 1):

As a software developer, you shouldn’t rely on undocumented behavior. Even if something works fine when you test it, if the documentation says “you must do it another way”, you generally have to forget your tests, and do as instructed. Otherwise your software can silently break down with the next windows update, including even the minor update.

Now on the batch/vbs files.

To run the CMD/BAT, call `GetEnvironmentVariable("ComSpec")` to obtain path to cmd.exe, then call CreateProcess specifying command=`cmd.exe`, arguments `/C path_to_CMD_file arg1 arg2`.
If the path or arguments contain space, you must include them in quotes. If the path or arguments contain spaces contain `"`, replace with `^"`.

To run VBS, call `ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%\\System32\\cscript.exe")` or wscript.exe, then pass VBS path in the first argument of the .exe file. If the path or an argument contain spaces or quotes, same rules apply to escaping.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I know about these ways and I know that relying on undocumented functions is not cool. But that doesn't answer my question - what could possible cause such effect, does work de-facto and, may be there is another piece of documentation which says 'you can run batch files with CreateProcess'?

Comment: Undocumented behavior is called undocumented precisely because there's no piece of documentation that documents the behavior.