# Java Execute an external program and capture the output

Tags: java, command-line

So i try to `Execute` an external program and capture the `output`.
Currently the part that execute command works fine (using `.bat` file) and i can see the output on the `cmd` window.

The part that need to read the output not and it seemt that it stack inside my `while`

This is what i have try:

```
String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/C", "Start", "d:\\batFile.bat"};
        Process process =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```

**Update**

This is my `.bat` file:

```
docker volume create --name=mydb
timeout 3
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v mydb:/data/db mongo
timeout 3
```

Comment: [Try to redirect the output](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-redirect-command-output-to-a-file-2618084)

Comment: This works but best way is to get this output using the code instead of open another file now

Comment: `start` in `cmd` by default creates a new console window and uses it directly for I/O, which the parent process (your Java) cannot intercept. Leave out the `start` and run directly with `cmd /c batfile` -- [or even execute it directly without specifying `cmd`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553379/createprocess-is-able-to-execute-batch-files-but-documentation-says-the-opposit)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to redirect the output like this :

```
Process runtimeProcess1;
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C","Start","d:\\batFile.bat");

pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
pb.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);
pb.redirectInput(Redirect.INHERIT);

runtimeProcess1 = pb.start();

int processComplete1 = runtimeProcess1.waitFor();
```

Comment: When i add the import for Redirect i got this compiler error: Usage of API documented as since 1.7+ less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info: This inspection finds all usages of methods that have @since tag in their documentation.

Comment: Even in j7 that does the _opposite_ of capturing the output.